# Drag and drop file electron/vue.js

Tags: vue.js, electron

I am trying to make an app with electron and vue.js, in this one I want to make a DropZone for file and just get the path of this file. My problem is that electron is opening my file like a file viewer. How can I disable it with vue.js ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `will-navigate` event is designed to catch/parse dropped files in electron. So it is not a vue.js specific issue.

This snippet will prevent the render process from loading the image as content.

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate', (event) => event.preventDefault());
```

- Reference: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5919
- API Docs: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#event-will-navigate